# No available plugins - Jenkins

Tags: amazon-ec2, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed a fresh jenkins on my amazon ec2 micro instance but when I access the plugin manager, I don't have any plugin available. What's wrong?

I used this guide to install
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins+on+Ubuntu

I'm running ubuntu 11.04 64 bits and jenkins-war:1.450

Looking my log file I see

```
"windmill": {"buildDate": "Feb 06, 2010", "dependencies": [], "developers": [{"developerId": "admc", "name": "Adam Christian"}], "excerpt": "This plugin allows you to configure and run <a href='http://www.getwindmill.com/'>Windmill</a> functional tests.", "labels": ["external"], "name": "windmill", "previousTimestamp": "2009-06-25T20:40:46.00Z", "previousVersion": "1.4", "releaseTimestamp": "2010-02-06T13:59:22.00Z", "requiredCore": "1.319", "scm": "svn.dev.java.net", "sha1": "npNnBKCCpnFCi+Tsw/QA1mQyyyI=", "title": "Windmill Plugin", "url": "http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/windmill/1.5/windmill.hpi", "version": "1.5", "wiki": "https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Windmill+Plugin"}, "ws-cleanup": {"buildDate": "Dec 07, 2011", "dependencies": [], "developers": [{"developerId": "
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:512)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextString(JSONTokener.java:244)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:352)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:875)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:170)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:355)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray._fromJSONTokener(JSONArray.java:917)
    at net.sf.json.JSONArray.fromObject(JSONArray.java:139)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:358)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:875)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:170)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:355)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:875)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:170)
    at net.sf.json.util.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:355)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromJSONTokener(JSONObject.java:875)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject._fromString(JSONObject.java:1064)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:176)
    at net.sf.json.JSONObject.fromObject(JSONObject.java:147)
    at hudson.model.UpdateSite.doPostBack(UpdateSite.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:282)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:149)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:88)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:563)
    ... 34 more
Jan 31, 2012 12:13:52 PM hudson.model.UpdateSite doPostBack
INFO: Obtained the latest update center data file for UpdateSource default
```

Comment: Since the guide you linked mentions a reverse proxy, note that there's a pitfall to avoid if you set the proxy to do HTTPS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674964/jenkins-apache-ssl-no-available-updates/22060275

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It looks like perhaps the Update Center JSON file which describes the available plugins was temporarily corrupt, or didn't get downloaded correctly.

I just tried downloading and parsing this file just now and it looks ok, so I would try triggering an update check manually.

Go to: Manage Jenkins → Manage Plugins → Advanced, then click <kbd>Check now</kbd> in the bottom right-hand corner.

Comment: Well It took long to update but now it's working, thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

The entry http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json
in the Manage-Plugins->Advanced->Update Site
is missing on some Linux - Flavours and if so, obviously you won't see any available plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have your jdk, ant, maven installed under the web interface under Configure System. You won't be able to use the jenkins cli to install plugins or see any available plugins in the web interface until you do this first.

Comment: This might be it! As iOS/python developer, I've never had any reason to install JDK/Ant/Maven and System config seems to say they are not available :)

Answer (score 1):

For what its worth, a workaround is to download the .hpi file for the plugin and upload into Jenkins.

[Index of Jenkins Plugins Available For Download](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/)

Answer (score 0):

did you check your ec2 security group: you may not have http/https outbound access to the plugin repository.

I have jenkins running on ec2 and plugin update center is reachable without problem: so, probably some changes in definition of your security group needed.

regards

didier

Answer (score 0):

If you have Jenkins running in EC2, it is definitely worth checking the security group. By default, secure HTTP is allowed outgoing but standard HTTP is not. The pre-set update center URL is http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json - changing it to https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json made all the difference in my case.