# Jenkins + Apache + SSL = no available updates

Tags: apache, ssl, jenkins, mod-ssl

I have followed this tutorial and many others:

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache

However, none of my attempts have been successful:

1. When I go to Plugin Manager -> Available, it says "No updates"
2. When I go to Plugin Manager -> Advanced -> Check Now, it says "Checking Updates..." and then nothing happens.
3. Looking at Apache and Tomcat logs, nothing shows up.
4. Looking at browser console, no errors appear. However, I get warnings like this one:

   [blocked] The page at 'https://mywebsite.com/jenkins/pluginManager/checkUpdates' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from 'http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/updates/hudson.tools.JDKInstaller.json.html?id=hudson.tools.JDKInstaller&version=1.544': this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.

Looking at this, I realize **the plugin manager wasn't designed for https**, because it makes ajax requests for non-SSL endpoints.

So what's the right solution to this? Is there an HTTPS endpoint to use for downloading plugins? Do I need to use a different browser?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

There is an HTTPS endpoint to use:

```
https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/update-center.json
```

Comment: While the endpoint is HTTPS, the URLs in the response are not. Thus completely defeating the purpose.

Comment: Ah. Does it still give AJAX warnings when you actually attempt to install a plugin? I didn't test that far.

Comment: I believe this is the relevant Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-20641

Comment: Hmm... the file already has SHA1 checksums as Kohsuke suggests in that Jenkins issue. Maybe the updater is already validating the plugin?

Comment: In case of SSL issue you may refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47709466/1802348)